# Ruby-SSH: Unable to use any of the Rye::Box::Cmd commands with fingerprint/HostKeyMismatch errors

Tags: ruby, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm using the Rye ruby gem to SSH to a server and I'm having the problem where if I try to run any command from there I'm getting the following error:

> rbox = Rye::Box.new(server, :user => "user", :password => "password")
>
> rbox.ls
>
> fingerprint d3:a1:15:ab:05:0d:4e:45:9f:b3:94:14:ca:11:d6:be does not match for "server,10.10.10.2"
>   Continue?
>
> Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch: Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch

```
    from C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rye-0.9.8/lib/rye/box.rb:678:in `connect'
    from C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rye-0.9.8/lib/rye/box.rb:778:in `run_command'
    from C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rye-0.9.8/lib/rye/cmd.rb:106:in `which'
    from (irb):31:in `evaluate'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1112:in `eval'
    from C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158:in `eval_input'
    from C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
    from C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:270:in `signal_status'
    from C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1439:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1212:in `catch'
    from C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
    from C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1212:in `catch'
    from C:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
    from C:\jruby-1.6.8\bin\irb:13:in `(root)'
```

I've tried deleting the 'known_hosts' file from the current user home (~/.ssh/known_hosts) but still failing with the same issue. 
I've tried connecting with a different user and same problem as well.

The strange thing is that that fingerprint is always displaying the same value, so not sure where it's coming from.

> rbox.keys    -> doesn't return anything, just []
>
> rye keys     -> NameError: undefined local variable or method `keys' for main:Object
>
> rbox.host_key -> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
>   => [, , 1, ]

Any idea what could be causing this issue and what else could I try to sort it out or work around it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This library is based on Ruby's Net::SSH and it is looking for cached host keys in ~/.ssh/known_hosts and /etc/ssh/knowh_hosts.
For more information see documentation on Net::SSH::KnownHosts.

Comment: In this case, I removed ~/.ssh/known_hosts and /etc/ssh/known_hosts doesn't even exists, so not sure where it's picking those values from?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that even though you connect from:

*Local_pc => *Middle_server => *Final_server

it doesn't matter in which of those 2 servers you are, it seems the 'known_hosts' file that's used is not that of any of those 2 servers, it's your LOCAL known_hosts file.

As such, you can either remove the entry for the specific host that's failing in your end or create the following .ssh/config file to ignore the host keys:

```
Host *
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

That config file is located in the following path in Windows:

```
C:\Users\<your_user>\.ssh\config
```